# XML Attribute to HTML select value using jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

I am new to jquery.I have an XML file contaning names of countries,states and cities.
I want to fill three HTML  of country,state and city by using jquery.I have done successfully to transform name of country to a html .But my Problem is i am unable to transform the xml attribute to  value.

My Xml file is as follows:

```
<Locations>
  <Countries>
    <CName index='1'>Afghanistan</CName>
    <CName index='2'>Algeria</CName>
    <CName index='36'>India</CName>
  </Countries>
  <States>
    <SName cindex='36' sindex='1' stype='st'>Andhra Pradesh</SName>
    <SName cindex='36' sindex='2' stype='st'>Arunachal Pradesh</SName>
    <SName cindex='36' sindex='3' stype='st'>Assam</SName>
  </States>
  <Cities>
    <cindex>36</cindex>
    <cityname sindex='1' ctype='ct'>Anantpur</cityname>
    <cityname sindex='1' ctype='ct'>Guntakal</cityname>
    <cityname sindex='1' ctype='ct'>Guntur</cityname>
    <cityname sindex='1' ctype='mct'>Hydrabad/Secundrabad</cityname>
  </Cities>
</Locations>
```

---

My HTML  is as follows:

```
<select id="CounList" class="drsel01">// For Country
 </select>

<select id="StateList"></select> //For State
```

### //For City

My JQuery Code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var spl_data;      

     // Loading Country
     $.get('Locations.xml', function(data) {
         spl_data = data;
         var that = $('#CounList');
         $('CName', spl_data).each(function() {
             $('<option>').text($(this).text()).appendTo(that); //
             $('<option>').value($(this).attr('index')).appendTo(that);

         });
     }, 'xml');
 });
```

```
 I want to country name to be fill in <option> text and value of index attribute to be filled as <option> value.So that when i choose a country then related name of states or cities which belongs to country will be filled.
```

I have successfully filled  text but not value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such method called `value()`. You should use `val()` method if you want to set the value of option element. Even after using `val()` your code will create 2 option elements and append them to CountList.

Try this instead

```
$('CName', spl_data).each(function() {
   $('<option />', { 
       text: $(this).text(),
       value: $(this).attr('index')
   }).appendTo(that);
});
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/qQ2Xw/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('<option>').val($(this).attr('index')).appendTo(that);
```

instead of:

```
$('<option>').value($(this).attr('index')).appendTo(that);
```

Comment: the above code is appending text and value one after one.Not for one <option>.